# My [neural-network] suggests to burninate this tag

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

While looking for tags appropriate for my new question I came across [neural-network](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neural-network) tag.

Currently, it only have a [single question (closed as off-topic)](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/184496/legal-consequences-of-ai) and no description. On said question, it doesn't really add anything that [artificial-intelligence](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence) doesn't already. Even if it did, it's rather hard to imagine when such addition would be relevant for valid World Building question.

As a result, my neural network (also commonly referred to as a brain or just me) suggest to get rid of this tag.

Comment: The tag was created more than 6 months ago, and is only used once, so the system should get rid of it automatically: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48418/295232

Comment: An lo, square-cube has burninated it.

Comment: @StarfishPrime had it more questions I would wait for a discussion, but in this case it was so clear the tag had no place that I don't feel bad about that. If a new question arises that really makes the tag worthy, most users can re-create it.

Comment: Yeah, I think for orphan tags like this is isn't too bad for people to take matters into their own hands.